# grab last n lines from console output

Tags: bash, shell, logging, gnu-screen

I want to make a shell script that will effectively grab the last n lines from sterr and stin that were outputted to the console. I have a screen session running a process that will restart it if it crashes via a hacky infinite loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script will be started in a screen session
counter=0
while [ $counter -lt 10 ]; do
    ./run_some_process;
     last_output=#GRAB PREVIOUS OUTPUT FROM CONSOLE HERE AND LOG TO FILE
     echo -e "$last_output" >> mylog.txt;
    sleep 5; #sleep for a few seconds before restarting
done
```

What I need is for the 7th line of code to grab the last 10 or so lines from stderr and stdin and append them to a log file

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
 ./run_some_process 2>&1 | tail -10 >>logfle
```

`tail -10` will give you last ten lines, `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout, `>>logfle` appends to logfile.

Comment: thanks! one lil' change: ./run_some_process 2>&1 | tail -10 >>logfle  Looks like stderr needed to go to stdout so it would make it to the pipe.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, my mistake ^^"

Comment: no need to write `tail -10`  since that is the default. `./run_some_process 2>&1 | tail >>logfle` would reach the same.